# Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax, me marca el error en los dos puntos

Tags: python-2.7, test

estoy aprendiendo Python con el libro "Learn Python the Hard Way" y hay un ejercicio con el que me he topado y no encuentro el error, el error se presenta cuando estoy haciendo pruebas con el comando "nosetests", he revisado los paréntesis, que todo tenga el mismo tipo de identación que son los errores relacionados a los ":" acá les dejo el código a ver si me pueden ayudar.

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex47.game import Room


def test_room():
    gold = Room("GoldRoom",
                """This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
                door to the north.""")
    assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
    assert_equal(gold.paths, [])
    
def test_room_paths():
    center = Room("Center", "Test room in the center.")
    north = Room("North", "Test room in the north.")
    south = Room("South", "Test room in the south.")
    
    center.add_paths(['north': north, 'south': south])
    assert_equal(center.go('north'), north)
    assert_equal(center.go('south'), south)

def test_map():
    start = Room("Start", "You can go west and down a hole.")
    west = Room("Trees", "There are trees here, you can go east.")
    down = Room("Dungeon", "It's dark down here, you can go up.")

    start.add_paths(['west': west, 'down': down])
    west.add_paths(['east': start])
    down.add_paths(['up': start])
    
    assert_equal(start.go('west'), west)
    assert_equal(start.go('west').go('east'), start)
    assert_equal(start.go('down').go('up'), start)
```

Estoy usando PowerShell como terminal y este es el error al ejecutar "nosetests"

```
PS C:$> nosetests
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: SyntaxError (invalid syntax (ex47_tests.py, line 17))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "C:$ ex47_tests.py", line 17
    center.add_paths(['north': north, 'south': south])
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.031s

FAILED (errors=1)
PS C:$
```

Comment: Los diccionarios en python se abren y cierran con llaves (`{'asd': 'qqq'}`) y no corchetes (`[ ]`).

Answer (score 1):

Estás utilizando corchetes cuando haces uso de diccionarios en lugar de utilizar llaves.

Recuerda que los tipos de datos que se definen con llaves son los:

- **sets**: por ejemplo: {1, 2, 3}
- **Diccionarios**: por ejemplo: {1 : "Adrian", 2: "Antonio"}

Luego con corchetes:

- **Listas**: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Con parentesis:

- **Tuplas**: (a, b, c, d, e)

El código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex47.game import Room

def test_room():
    gold = Room("GoldRoom",
                """This room has gold in it you can grab. There's a
                door to the north.""")
    assert_equal(gold.name, "GoldRoom")
    assert_equal(gold.paths, [])

def test_room_paths():
    center = Room("Center", "Test room in the center.")
    north = Room("North", "Test room in the north.")
    south = Room("South", "Test room in the south.")

    center.add_paths({'north': north, 'south': south})
    assert_equal(center.go('north'), north)
    assert_equal(center.go('south'), south)

def test_map():
    start = Room("Start", "You can go west and down a hole.")
    west = Room("Trees", "There are trees here, you can go east.")
    down = Room("Dungeon", "It's dark down here, you can go up.")

    start.add_paths({'west': west, 'down': down})
    west.add_paths({'east': start})
    down.add_paths({'up': start})

    assert_equal(start.go('west'), west)
    assert_equal(start.go('west').go('east'), start)
    assert_equal(start.go('down').go('up'), start)
```